# Concave function with bounded derivative.

Tags: derivatives, convex-analysis

I am looking for an example of a concave function whose derivative is bounded over $\mathbb{R}$. Could someone provide such an example?

Comment: Does $y = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$ suit? Its concave and has a continuous bounded gradient. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witch_of_Agnesi

Comment: @psychgiraffe $\frac1{1+x^2}$ is not concave because $f''(1)>0$.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio is correct, my earlier function wasn't concave. If you allow parametric functions then I believe $x = -\sinh(t) \ , \ y = -\cosh(t)$ with $-\infty < t < \infty$ works (please correct me if I'm wrong). This is just the bottom branch of a hyperbola.

Comment: what about $f(x) = mx+n$  for some $m,n$